# Error : - _BFTaskErrorDomain", referenced from

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i compile the code i am facing error like that, i can not understand actually, someone can solve this error please, my project is stuck for these errors.

Thank you for everyone who give me solution or any kind of suggestion that will become solution.

"_BFTaskErrorDomain", referenced from:

```
  ___63-[PFObjectBatchController deleteObjectsAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke103 in Parse(PFObjectBatchController.o)
```

"_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:

```
  ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke216 in Parse(PFObject.o)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFCancellationTokenSource", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObjectBatchController.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(ParseManager.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFAnalyticsController.o)





  ...
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFAsyncTaskQueue.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyPin.o)





  ...
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFAsyncTaskQueue.o)





  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchaseController.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)





  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)





  ...
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in FacebookPostController.o





 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FacebookPostController)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LibFacebook", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in VLViewController.o
```

"_kBFMultipleErrorsError", referenced from:

```
  ___63-[PFObjectBatchController deleteObjectsAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke103 in Parse(PFObjectBatchController.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete DerivedData then clean your project and run it.